# PHP: copying files, which are simultaneously written

Tags: php, copy

I'm currently writing a PHP script, which should import some sensor data. To do so, I copy the sent file (of the sensor) from the FTP server to another location, before I start importing the data into the database.
When I use **copy** or **rename** to move the file from the FTP location to another location within php, I sometimes get an PHP warning:

`[30-Apr-2020 04:15:02 Europe/Zurich] PHP Warning:  copy(<File location on FTP server>): failed to open stream: Permission denied in <Location of PHP file> on line 1830`

I guess that warning occurs, when the sensor is writing its data simultaneously onto the FTP location, while I try to copy or move the data file. Is there any way to check, if the sensor is currently writing to this file, while I try to copy?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is showing the error exactly, you can check if you have provided the write permission for the directory/file mentioned on line 1830

Comment: If you get that warning the file is not at the location. You have any code?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld how does "permission denied" mean that the file is not at the location?? "Permission denied" means exactly what it says - you don't have permission to open the file. It says nothing about the existence of the file.

Comment: @ADyson - aha sorry. My bad. I read this question to fast. I just read  "failed to open stream". You're absolutely right!

Comment: Is there any other method to open the file without iterrupting the data logger currently writing to it on the ftp? This could maybe be the solution... Or can I check, if I have permission to open the file?